# How to handle any request coming to my virtual wifi hotspot in Windows 7

Tags: c#, dns, wifi, virtual

I want to **take control over all the requests** which arrive to the **virtual wifi hotspot**.

I opened up a wifi hotspot via Microsoft Virtual WiFi Mini Adaptor through command prompt. I used **netsh wlan start hostednetwork**. I also put it into **static ip mode** to overcome with the *android stuck at obtaining ip address issue*. Everything is working fine.

Some time ago I built a **server software with C# which binds to internal ip address** of the wifi hotspot. I use it as a file server, remote computer controlling purposes.

**Here is core section:** If you connect to the hotspot from a device like android phone or pc, open the browser and **type `http://192.168.137.1:8080/` (hotspot pc ip address) on address bar, you simply connect to it** and a home page appears and so on. But I want every client to be redirected to my server.

So **regardless of what they put into address bar like google.com, facebook, yahoo, they will be redirected to my server** and visit its homepage. This is something like controlling DNS, I guess. Is it possible to take control over every request that way?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. First of all I need a DHCP server.

Here is one: http://tftpd32.jounin.net/

This also may help: http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-DHCP-on-a-Local-Area-Network

With this program I can run and configure its DHCP server. I need to set the DNS server address to my own servers address (like 192.168.0.1 which is default gateway). So when clients connect to my virtual hotspot, they will receive this as a DNS server address. Clients will request every domain name from that address (instead of 8.8.8.8 which is Google Public DNS for example). So I also need a DNS server of my own. It must be bound to port 53 (192.168.0.1:53 with UDP protocol, not TCP!!) which is default DNS port number. Main server must be bound to 192.168.0.1:80 with TCP. Notice that it is bound to HTTP port.

If everything goes fine after doing these, my DNS server will give main servers IP address to clients regardless of the domain name IP they requested. Hence they will connect to my server instead of real ones (facebook,youtube etc).

By the way the DHCP server program which I given the url of is working very well for me. It is very simple and efficient. It will eliminate issues like "Android stuck at obtaining IP address". It also provides other servers such as TFTP, SNTP, SysLog and DNS. It also works so fine even without any advanced virtual hotspot program (such as Connectify). You may only call "netsh wlan start hostednetwork" command. I don't intent any promotion here. I'm just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want redirecting all domain search queries to your ip address you have to control the DNS.

The best way is to operate as a proxy service between your client and the destination, so you can manipulate the query of the client.

Comment: I enabled proxy and set its ip and port to those of my server. When you open a web browser and enter any domain it connects to my server. This is what I want but unfortunately it only seems to work on the hotspot pc only. External clients aren't affected by this proxy setting so when you do the same on another device it doesnt load anything. I heard that some people achieved similiar job. They could attach domain name to their LAN server.